# jQuery UI Sortable: Revert changes if update callback makes an AJAX call that fails?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using the sortable widget to re-order a list of items. After an item is dragged to a new location, I kick off an AJAX form post to the server to save the new order. How can I undo the sort (e.g. return the drag item to its original position in the list) if I receive an error message from the server?

Basically, I only want the re-order to "stick" if the server confirms that the changes were saved.

Comment: Please reconsider which answer should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that sortable doesn't have any undo-last-drop function -- but it's a great idea!

In the mean time, though, I think your best bet is to write some sort of `start` that stores the ordering, and then on failure call a revert function.  I.e. something like this:

```
$("list-container").sortable({
  start: function () { 
           /* stash current order of sorted elements in an array */
         },
  update: function () {
          /* ajax call; on failure, re-order based on the stashed order */
         }
});
```

Would love to know if others have a better answer, though.

Comment: I just clone the whole sortable initially on page load and stuff it into a variable for safe keeping.  On ajax save success I replace the clone variable with the latest sortable (clone again).  On error I replace the sortable with the clone (and reinitialize it as a sortable).  Seems to be working okay so far...

Comment: Could you please post this as an answer so it can be upvoted? :)

Answer (score 35):

Try the following:

```
$(this).sortable('cancel');
```

Comment: This worked for me, although I was posting one update at a time.

Comment: ajax is usually asynchronous so for this to actually work you would have to wait/sleep in the sortable beforeStop method for the ajax request, perhaps by setting async to false on the jquery request.

Comment: @Ryan I used `$elem.sortable('cancel')` to _undo_ UI sorting if the backend failed to persist changes and it it just worked. It seems `cancel` undoes the **last modification** to the arrangement of the items no mater how much time has passed (unless one refreshes the page or something).

Comment: Thank you! helped me

Answer (score 8):

I just encountered this same issue, and for the sake of a complete answer, I wanted to share my solution to this problem:

```
$('.list').sortable({
  items:'.list:not(.loading)',
  start: function(event,ui) { 
    var element = $(ui.item[0]);
    element.data('lastParent', element.parent());
  },
  update: function(event,ui) {
    var element = $(ui.item[0]);
    if (element.hasClass('loading')) return;
    element.addClass('loading');
    $.ajax({
      url:'/ajax',
      context:element,
      complete:function(xhr,status) {
        $(this).removeClass('loading');
        if (xhr.status != 200) {
          $($(this).data('lastParent')).append(this);
        }
      },
    });
  }
});
```

You'll need to modify it to suit your codebase, but this is a completely multithread safe solution that works very well for me.