# How to revert the table row position after cancel the confirmation button in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I want to Revert the position after dragging.

There is a table in my system. Its rows can be dragged and change the position. According to the dragging order also be changed. But before changing the order confirmation message pop up and if we approve it change the position and change the order number. It has been completed well.

If we cancel the confirmation dragging should be reverted. But that part not working well. It is the problem I have. I have mentioned the tried code below. Where should I change to fix this?

Tried Javascript code:

```
var fixHelperModified = function(e, tr) {
  var $originals = tr.children();
  var $helper = tr.clone();
  $helper.children().each(function(index) {
      $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
  });
  return $helper;
}
  updateIndex = function(e, ui) {
    if(window.confirm("Do you really want to update the order?")){
      $('td.index', ui.item.parent()).each(function (i) {
          $(this).html(i + 1);
      });
    }else{
      $("#table tbody").draggable({
        revert: "invalid";
    });
    }
  };


  $("#table tbody").sortable({
    helper: fixHelperModified,
    stop: updateIndex
  }).disableSelection();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery UI Sortable: Revert changes if update callback makes an AJAX call that fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700130/jquery-ui-sortable-revert-changes-if-update-callback-makes-an-ajax-call-that-fa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(this).sortable('cancel');
```

```js
//$('table tbody').sortable();

var fixHelperModified = function(e, tr) {
  var $originals = tr.children();
  var $helper = tr.clone();
  $helper.children().each(function(index) {
      $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
  });
  return $helper;
}
var updateIndex = function(e, ui) {
  if(window.confirm("Do you really want to update the order?")){
    $('td.index', ui.item.parent()).each(function (i) {
        $(this).html(i + 1);
    });
  }else{
    
    $(this).sortable('cancel');
  }
};


$("table tbody").sortable({
  helper: fixHelperModified,
  stop: updateIndex,
  revert: '100'
}).disableSelection();
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
  #sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
  #sortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em; }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>1- Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2- Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3- Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4- Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5- Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6- Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
 
</body>
</html>
```

[duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700130/jquery-ui-sortable-revert-changes-if-update-callback-makes-an-ajax-call-that-fa/9460754)